# jquery ui combobox dropdown menu bring to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I'm using the jquery ui combobox inside jquery accodrdion propblem I'm having is if the combobox dropdown menu extends past the accordion section it gets hidden behind. I think it might have something to do with the z-indez but when I try and retrieve the values to see if that's the problem I get 'auto' which is no help. I added a screen shot to show what I'm trying to explain as the problem.

[image: combobox drop down menu]

Here's a jsfiddle...
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jf7cngd/29/)

```
$('select').combobox();
```

EDIT: working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jf7cngd/55/)

what I changed...

removed position

```
.ui-combobox { display: inline-block; margin: 0; margin-right: 1.8em; }
```

Changed position to relative, was absolute. added height. and changed top: -2px, use to be 0.

```
.ui-combobox-button { position: relative; height: 24px; width: 1.8em !important; margin: 0; margin-left: -1px; top: -2px; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: cant say without looking at your code.

Comment: @Lucky Chingi didn't want to add unnecessarily long code and not sure what would help.

Comment: you can at the very least add the html and the css for those elements, just sharing a screenshot invites downvotes. Better create a codepen :)

Comment: Ok let me see what I can add :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with positioning, here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jf7cngd/55/) with new css code.

```
.ui-combobox { display: inline-block; margin: 0; margin-right: 1.8em; }
.ui-combobox-button { position: relative; height: 24px; width: 1.8em !important; margin: 0; margin-left: -1px; top: -2px; bottom: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]I checked codepen and the z-index does not apply, maybe I am not doing it right, but I did add a Jquery code and it works!.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-button-icon-primary").click(function(){
        $("#sinkDetails").height($(this).height()*15); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried adding that code to my jsfiddle and still doesn't work... my turn for maybe not doing it right.

Comment: ok... I can't get it to work but I think what the code is doing is actually making the accordion section heigher so the drop down menu fits. Is that what it's doing?

Comment: yep! the script calculated the current height of the select box and increases the height of the fieldset

Comment: That's actually pretty cool and could be an option but I really like it to go 'over' the other elements if possible.

Comment: you can also set the position to fixed for the UL and adjust the top and left positions, but that may not be good for a responsive layout

Comment: I'm kind of doing something like that now where if the drop down is hidden I move it up or down so it's visible. But having the other option of bringing it to the front would be nice also in some cases where the menu is longer then the accordion section regardless of it's position. That's where you're code could come in handy. ;)